# Swiftmailer raise an exception with code 554, client host rejected

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer to send mail through a contact form with  Symfony. My ISP allows me to send mail from a remote server with my mail account information (username, password and smtp). 
My problem is that when I'm sending a mail from my development site (from my desktop server) I can do it and the mail is sent, but in the production environment Swiftmailer raise an exception saying that the client host is rejected (code 554 5.7.1) and failed to send the mail. I have tried to debug this with the `app/console swiftmailer:email:send` and I get the same error :

```
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: 
 Expected response code 220 but got code "554", 
 with message "554 5.7.1 <unknown[here-example-ipv6]:49545>: 
 Client host rejected: Access denied " [] []
```

The ipv6 (here-example-ipv6) is corresponding to a dns of my host that I have not configured, but I don't understand why Swiftmailer believes that this ip is corresponding to the client host, my configuration seems (app/config/config.yml and parameters.yml) to be good because that's work fine from my desktop. Any help would be appreciated, thank.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get it. I was confused with the error message because I thought it was comming from Switmailler, but it was comming from my ISP mail server.
The problem was that when you want to send a mail from a remote location my ISP require to activate SSL encryption.
So I have added two more parameters for the Swfitmailler configuration :

```
port: 465
encryption: ssl
```

and now that's fine. But because I was testing from a production environment, the cache has to be cleared in order the changes to take effect.